# Can you see NHibernate results mid-query during debugging in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Having been comfortably using Entity Framework for many years, I've just been thrown in the deep end with a project that uses NHibernate and I'm really struggling. The documentation is sparse and unhelpful if you're working with it for the first time, and most tutorial and example sites are out of date - I understand it changed significantly in v3?

Normally, I learn things best when trying to work with them, so I jumped in and tried to see what I could do. But I've hit a bug in this pre-existing function (none of this code is mine):

```
public IDictionary<long, string> GetSeriesFilterData(string userId)
{
    Series seriesAlias = null;
    Event eventAlias = null;
    Session sessionAlias = null;
    Dealership dealershipAlias = null;

    var query = _repository.Session.QueryOver(() => seriesAlias)
        .Where(() => !seriesAlias.IsArchived);

    var dealershipIds = QueryOver.Of<ApplicationUserDealership>()
        .Where(x => x.ApplicationUser_Key == userId)
        .SelectList(list => list.SelectGroup(x => x.Dealership_Id));

    dealershipIds.Where(x => x.Dealership_Id == dealershipAlias.Id);
    query
        .JoinAlias(() => sessionAlias.Dealership, () => dealershipAlias, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
        .WithSubquery.WhereExists(dealershipIds);


    var results = query.SelectList(x => x
            .SelectGroup(() => seriesAlias.Id)
            .SelectGroup(() => seriesAlias.Name))
        .List<object[]>()
        .ToDictionary(x => (long) x[0], x => (string) x[1]);

    return results;
}
```

The exception, thrown when collecting the result, is:

> An exception of type 'NHibernate.QueryException' occurred in NHibernate.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: could not resolve property: sessionAlias

My suspicion is that this is because dealershipIds is empty, but I'm struggling to prove that this is the case. Working with Entity Framework, it's possible to see the results of a query during debugging by unpacking its object graph. However, I can't seem to do that in NHibernate.

Is it possible to see the results of a query fragment via debugging, or do I have to pull it out with a Select statement?

Comment: There are no intermediate results in NHibernate, the whole stuff is tinkered to a query and executed in the database. The exception message tells you that he can't build the sql query. The QueryOver don't know where `sessionAlias` is defined. Sadly, i am unable to help you, because my QueryOver knowledge is more than rusty. But i hope this points you in the right direction. Just ask SO for `QueryOver` and `Alias`.

Comment: @mjwills That was my first thought, but my (limited) understanding is that it's *supposed* to be null, Docs says "In QueryOver, aliases are assigned using an empty variable. The variable can be declared anywhere (but should be null at runtime)" - which doesn't make a lot of sense to me TBH. I assumed it's some kind of placeholder but ...

Comment: @mjwills http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover

Comment: The alias must be null. They are just a placeholder to access the properties of the entities. At first, it is really strange to write the code like this, but it is intended. Just see it more like `item => item.Property` in linq.

Comment: `Cat catAlias = null;
Kitten kittenAlias = null;

IQueryOver<Cat,Cat> catQuery =
    session.QueryOver<Cat>(() => catAlias)
        .JoinAlias(() => catAlias.Kittens, () => kittenAlias)
        .Where(() => catAlias.Age > 5)
        .And(() => kittenAlias.Name == "Tiddles")` Is the code from the linked article. See how `catAlias` appears before `catAlias.Kittens`. That appears different to the (non-working) code in question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QueryOver you've posted seems to be missing the part where the 
`sessionAlias` alias is assigned to something.

As it's being done for the others (except `eventAlias` which seems completely unused) the alias needs to be assigned to a property/path on the entity class being queried via `JoinAlias`/`JoinQueryOver` or to the entity itself as it's done on the QueryOver creation with `seriesAlias`.

Then, that alias (variable) can be used in `Where`, `OrderBy`, etc.

For example, supposing that Session is an entity referenced from a property of `Series` (no clue regarding your actual entity model) the following would fix your problem as it will bind `sessionAlias` to that property:

```
// This binds the alias to the property.
query.JoinAlias(s => s.Session, () => sessionAlias);

// This is the same as above, but uses the previously defined alias for the main entity, 
// just to show how aliases can be used.
query.JoinAlias(() => seriesAlias.Session, () => sessionAlias);
```